Check if a part is a part of a character | Roblox
I am not sure where to start so asking for some help. I want to create a script that detects if the part is hit by a person.
Can anyone give an idea?
local Debris = game:GetService("Debris")
local wall = script.Parent

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name ~= "Rails" then
        if hit.Name ~= "Baseplate" then
            if hit.Name ~= "Essential" then
                local explode = Instance.new("Explosion")
                explode.Parent = hit
                explode.Position = hit.Position
                hit:BreakJoints()
                Debris:AddItem(hit, 5)
            end
        end
    end
end)

Thanks

We can use FindFirstAncestorOfClass and FindFirstChild together for finding whether a part is a child of the Player.Character.
If hit has a Model ancestor and that ancestor has a Humanoid, we can assume that Model is the Player.Character.
In the below script, I made it so that whenever script.Parent is touched we check for a Model ancestor and then if that Model has a Humanoid. If so we add an explosion to it.
local Debris = game:GetService("Debris")
local wall = script.Parent

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local characterModel = hit:FindFirstAncestorOfClass("Model")
    if characterModel then
        local humanoid = characterModel:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
        if humanoid then
            local explode = Instance.new("Explosion")
            explode.Parent = hit
            explode.Position = hit.Position
            hit:BreakJoints()
            Debris:AddItem(hit, 5)
        end
    end
end)

Note that you may need to modify the code for explode. It is unclear in your question what to do if we hit the Player so I left it as is.
You can use hit for the Player's Part we hit, humanoid for the Player's Humanoid and characterModel for the the Player's Character.

this could false on a npc

@Yorick Yes it could be false on NPCs without a Humanoid but since we only want to find the Player this should be fine. Most of the time though NPCs will use Humanoid because they need to walk around or do things only an Humanoid can do (at least without reinventing Humanoids)

this would also count accessories/tool as a hitbox wich would give some players a disadvantage to others. @Ryan

@Yorick You can toggle whether accessories count towards the player collision in Game Settings. You would set it to inner collision meaning only the actual rig would trigger the .Touched event and you can have accessories as big as you want while no affecting the player’s experience other than maybe visibility. See Collision Boundaries for more.

.Touched event is tied to network ownership so it does not matter if you created a collision setting for this. if the client has network ownership over their accessory (which it does) it would fire the event resulting in a disadvantage to some players

you can check if a hit part is a part inside of a character by checking if the parent is a character using the GetPlayerFromCharacter method.
local Players = game:GetService("Players");

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local Character = hit.Parent
    local Player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Character);
       
   if (not Player) then return; end -- exit function, no player touched

   local explode = Instance.new("Explosion", hit);
   explode.Position = hit.Position;
   hit:BreakJoints();
   Debris:AddItem(hit, 5);
end);


hit.Parent might give a false negative if a part is nested like Character.Part.Part. It would return false though it's still a part of the Character with your method. While it works if a part is Character.Part, any further than that like Character.Part.Part.Part, it will return false. I would suggest you use hit:FindFirstAncestorOfClass("Model") so we can find a parent that is a Model class but this is also prone to failure if we have Character.Model.Model, but my answer still has that issue as well.

@RyanLuu i disagree because accessories / tools shouldnt be part of the hitbox ;)
